# Issue with Jenkins failure error for Hello World java code

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to learn Jenkins and Git. I have created a simple Freestyle project which takes a simple source code below from git and and prints Hello, World. The Hello_java file commits to git fine.

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        system.out.ptintIn ("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

The console output gives error below

> Error: Could not find or lead main class Hello

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. Are you expecting Jenkins to compile and run this Java snippet? Please [edit] this question and tell us what you want to do, show what you have tried, and tell us what went wrong. BTW, that code will not compile.

Comment: You're probably getting that error because you forgot to compile the Java program (hint: `javac Hello.java`). It should work if you fix the errors and compile and run your program.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I have got Jenkins to compile and run .java file
Javac Hello.java
Java Hello

I think its something to do with Jenkins fetching the file from Git and unable to do so?

Comment: Thank you all for your response. If you see the Hello class code I was using 's' instead of capital 'S' in System.out. only had to change it and it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when there is a problem with the .class file. To run this program, you need the .class file that is created when you compile the .java file. Have you compiled it (or gotten Jenkins to compile it for you)? If not, you have to do:

```
javac Hello.java
```

Then, you should be able to run:

```
java Hello
```

And everything should work.

Comment: @M B, Thank you for your response. I was using 's' instead of capital 'S' in System.out. only had to change it and it all worked and created the .class file and and hence java Hello.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!
See [this](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/hello-world/) tutorial .

Steps:

- code that compiles locally correctly committed in a git repo in github/bitbucket/own server etc
- add a jenkins file in the repo based on the tutorial
- add git repo credentials ( app password) in jenkins secrets (manage jenkins area )
- create a jenkins job in pipeline mode and add your repo and select the credential and the path to your jenkins file

[image]

- build

As later steps you want to see what to do with the deliverables obtained (.jar .war files etc) .
You can pack them and download from jenkins (easiest), store them in a repo (like artifactory/nexus) or build a container image with the server running that jar and push it to a docker repository (private dockerhub, gcp, aws etc) .

Note: jenkins server should have docker installed in order to get maximum flexibility from it.